# Using the umount command

Tags: linux, mount, disk

I tried umounting a sdfs disk, but I can only unmount it using the `umount -l` command.

The command `mount` returns the disks currently occupyed.
I would like some help to understand the meanings of the `umount -l` command.

Comment: Have you read the man page? (`man umount`)

Answer (score 2):

When you try to unmount a filesystem, the kernel checks that no processes are still using it. That is, if there's some process that's still reading from or writing to a file on that mountpoint, or has a directory as its current directory, or something along those lines, then you can't unmount that filesystem, because it's still in use.

`umount -l` doesn't *actually* unmount the filesystem; it just "hides" the mount until all those processes that had files or directories open on it, stop having them open. At that point, the filesystem is finally really unmounted.

This can be useful for disconnecting "hung" network mounts or the like, so as to avoid extra processes trying to read from the hung network mount; otherwise these extra processes would all get blocked while the system waits for the network mount to start working again, which is not a useful state to be in.

For everything else, the `-l` option to `umount` is usually a *very* bad idea. If you're trying to unmount a local disk so you can remove it from the system, since `umount -l` doesn't actually unmount the disk until later, removing the disk after the `umount -l` command finishes will result in the disk being removed while it's still in use, and may cause data loss.

Instead, if you wish to unmount the disk while it's still in use, you should make sure that no processes are using the mount point. You can get an overview of those processes that do by running `fuser -m <mountpoint>`; e.g., if your disk is mounted as `/mnt/disk`, then run `fuser -m /mnt/disk` to get the list of processes that still use it. You can then either stop those processes, or instruct them to close the files that they have open on the filesystem, or whatever, before trying the `umount` again.